# crypt AES mode ECB in objective c and php

Tags: php, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this AES encryption on an iPad and decryption in PHP fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060392/why-does-this-aes-encryption-on-an-ipad-and-decryption-in-php-fail)

I use objective c to encrypt data and php to decrypt

this my code in objective c

```
NSString *log=[@"enfin on a terminé le projet de cette anné" AES256EncryptWithKey:key]; 
NSString *decr=[@"k6MDFVLV3UrxD63xc1gZBQ==" AES256DecryptWithKey:key];
```

and this my function in php

```
$key = "1234567891234567";

$st = urldecode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$key, $tmp_st, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
echo("<br>");
// decrypted data
echo "decryptage de (admin) de objective c : ". $st ;
```

now all work ,but when i use big string more 18 string this code not work

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Please update your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the common `AES256EncryptWithKey:` that I've seen lots of people copy (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840374/iphone-encryption-not-working)), it uses CBC, not ECB. It also unfortunately hard-codes the IV to `NULL`.

Your PHP code appears to be generating a random IV, which is correct for encryption (though `AES256EncryptWithKey:` doesn't do so), but incorrect for decryption.

I'm not familiar with the syntax for `mcrypt_decrypt`, but you appear to be passing a 144 bit key to it (18 bytes). The data is encrypted with a 256-bit key. I don't see what key you're using in your ObjC. A key is not a password (`AES256EncryptWithKey:` unfortunately treats it like it is).

You can see [Properly encrypting with AES with CommonCrypto](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564) for more details on how to use CommonCrypto. As I note in the article "it’s a good idea to actually understand this code, not just copy it." That's critical for your PHP decrypt logic as well. You should make sure you carefully read the documentation on `mcrypt_decrypt`.